# Cannot create a new AVD. No sufficiently recent Android SDK available

Tags: android, qt

So I get this error when trying to create a new android device in AVD:
[image]

I'm able to create devices on android studio, but I can't use them in qt for some reason. I have all API since 18 to 25 on AS (am I missing anything?)[image]

Here are my settings of android on qt: 
[image]

I'm using the auto-generated kit for android provided by qt. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem solved? How to solve it?

Comment: I just saw this. Yes I did. Let me look at what the answers was.

Comment: Dang sorry I took so long with this. I think this still may help other people: If I remember right I just replace the sdk tools inside my sdk folder. Here is a list where you can find previous releases
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

can you  try starting the emulator from the command line using

emulator avd avd_name
 or emulator @avd_name

Comment: yes I can actually start them independently, but qt creator still doesn't recognize them. They show as incompatible ("ABI is incompatible, device supports ABIs: x86.")